# ios 8 : ABPeoplePickerNavigationController dismiss on implementing people picker delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, abpeoplepickerview, ios8.1

This is strange behavior noticed while accessing contact details from address book in ios 8.
My scenario is simple

1. Show contacts table
2. select a row that will invoke didSelectPerson method
3. in didSelectPerson method
4. push SecondViewController

   ```
   - (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person;
   {
       SecondViewController *detailVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
       [detailVC.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
       //    [peoplePicker.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
       [peoplePicker pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
   }
   ```

but what happens is ABPeoplePickerNavigationController dismiss.
Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: Can't firgure it out either, and i'm having the exact same issue ^^

Empty method but, as soon as its called, the picker is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the philosophy thing what happens under the hood of the "**didSelectPerson**" method, me was facing the same problem today. I found a simple solution to overcome this issue, i override the 
"**-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion**" method of the "**ABPeoplePickerNavigationController**". Then implement it like somewhat following

```
    bool dismissedEnabled;
   -(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
   {
     if (dismissedEnabled) {
       [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
     }
   }
```

then inside the "**didSelectPerson**"  i have done the following

```
   viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    dismissedEnabled = false;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this works for me, hope you guys overcome it too :)

Comment: In order to do this, I subclass the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and it worked fine for me.  But Apple's doc stated that "The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing."  Did Apple reject your app?

Comment: Until now, not rejected yet due to subclassing the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. If you get rejected or in doubt, you can override this method by using category feature described here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: We overlooked something quite simple:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354402/the-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-class-does-not-support-subclassing

Answer (score 0):

It automatically dismisses if you select a contact with a single email address for example.
If a contact has more than one email, you must specify a predicate that will force the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to push a ABPersonViewController on the stack.

```
if ([picker respondsToSelector:@selector(setPredicateForSelectionOfPerson:)])
    {
        // The people picker will select a person that has exactly one email address and call peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:,
        // otherwise the people picker will present an ABPersonViewController for the user to pick one of the email addresses.
        picker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailAddresses.@count = 1"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default behavior in iOS 8 is that the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is automatically dismissed when didSelectPerson is called.

The reason that the `SecondViewController` is not displayed (I'm inferring that this is the problem symptom) is because you are trying to push the `SecondViewController` while the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is being dismissed. This overlapping animation is a problem that the iOS core view management/animation system tries to avoid.

You may get a warning in the console when this happens.

@Ratul's solution works because it circumvents this default behavior.

In my scenario, my code sleeps a second before presenting a `UIAlertController` from within `didSelectPerson`. This is a hack that depends on the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` dismissal animation taking less than a second. For me, if this alert is not displayed, nobody would even notice this was a problem.

If you want something more robust, you may want to override `viewDidAppear` to handle this special case (using a flag in your presenting view controller). But this gets a bit clumsy as well.