# The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing

Tags: ios

In using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, `didSelecPerson` delegate will get called when user selects a person and then the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` dismisses itself.  I need to present another view controller when receiving `didSelectPerson` call.  The issue is `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`'s animation dismissing at this stage is not complete.  So, the presentation of the next view controller will generate an error.

If I subclass `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and override:

```
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];

    [self.myDelegate didDismissPickerCompletion];
}
```

That will solve the problem.  But the Apple doc did state "The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing".  Does that mean they will reject any attempt to subclass such stated class?

note:  I do not wish to use any artificial time delay as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and then the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController dismisses itself

There's your problem. It is dismissing itself only because *you* did not dismiss it. Dismiss it, explicitly, yourself! Call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` right there in your `didSelectPerson:` implemention.

Now you have a completion handler, and so you can run code when the dismissal has finished.